# Export Google Slides as separate pages with markup HTML (site generation)

Tags: html, github-pages, markup, google-slides-api, google-slides

Is there a way to export google slides as HTML pages with markup ?
Or what way could I take to adapt a published presentation exported for web, to include markups?

In a way, I wanna use Google Slides as a HTML generator. I aim to publish a portfolio on github pages - I need to edit final HTML to include hyperlinks between slides or a menu to navigate slides, and edit titles and sections with appropriate HTML markups.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways:

1. Embedding the slide: `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<file Id>/embed`. You can add this on an iframe.
2. Use the API (or Google Apps Script) to go slide by slide and recreate it using HTML.

Comment: option 1 does not allow to modify HTML. could you elaborate answer to show how use API for interacting with HTML slide by slide ? Or export in HTML ?

Comment: @user305883 Not sure what you'd like to change but you can add links (including to other slides) in the presentation itself. Also you can change almost all styles. If you do that, you wouldn't need to modify it before uploading.

Comment: @user305883 As for the second option it's basically using the [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/overview) to go page by page and convert it to a format you like.

Comment: I wanna include a menu to navigate through the slide. Slides will be full page when published, I 'd like to make a menu (a side bar or top bar)

Comment: @user305883 Maybe you have a third option: export as SVG and control which one is shown using JavaScript

Comment: thank you for thinking about a third one, SVG would not fix. Eventually, possible to download slide per slide as HTML pages - with correct HTML markup ?

Comment: @user305883 Googles doesn't provide an endpoint to download as HTML. The only option would be to recreate it based on the information that you can acquire using the API. That means: reading slide by slide where are the items and what are they and recreating the HTML to show the same. This would be a big project, and I'm not making it. Feel free to try for yourself and, if you get stuck, open a new question.

Comment: @user305883 Also, SVG can  be inlined on HTML, can have links, and can be modified. So I'm not sure why doesn't work for you.

Comment: Maintenance for automating the process and possibility to structure the slides with HTML tags